# Typing backtick in GitHub on Firefox does not create a full-width character

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-layout, github, dead-keys

Whenever I type backticks in the GitHub comment textbox, the next character will always be shown in the same spot as the backtick, as if the width of the backtick character is 0. This only happens on Firefox, and as far as I can tell, only on GitHub's comment textbox and searchboxes.

Here's how it looks when I type `test`:

This is on Firefox:

[image: Firefox example]

This is on Chromium:

[image: Chromium example]

I typed the exact same thing, but on Firefox, it prints the next character on top of the backtick.

If I type 3 backticks in a row, it won't look like ```, but like a much bolder single backtick.

I also noticed similar behaviour on bugs.archlinux.org, where backticks in posted comments look like this on Firefox (but they are in the correct place on Chromium):

[image: bugs.archlinux.org example on Firefox]

If I type my own comment, backticks type normally in the editor of bugs.archlinux.org.

This happens on both X11 (bspwm) and Wayland (Hyprland), and has been happening for I think at least 6 months. It doesn't happen on any of my other systems, just this laptop which is running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this a while back too. It's a problem with your fonts.

What worked for me was purging all the font directories and reinstalling the fonts I needed. AFAIK it was just one faulty font, somewhere, that firefox would insist on using.

You might also want to remove all fonts you have, and install them one by one and test when firefox starts doing this to find the wonky font.

Some bells ring to me to check what font the text is using F12 (inspect element)

Some websites force windows-esque fonts like Arial or Tahoma, and if you have them, some might be working incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks @Vaxry, The text editor was using Noto Sans, so I fixed the problem by uninstalling Noto fonts, which was installed under ~/.local/share/fonts/Noto_Sans.